# How do I efficiently split a mysql table into multiple tables (splitting on columns not on rows)?

Tags: mysql, database

For example

**Old Table:** EmployeeID | Employee Name | Role | DepartmentID | Department Name | Department Address

To be split to

**Table 1:** Employee ID | Employee Name | Role | DepartmentID

**Table 2:** DepartmentID | Department Name | Department Address

This is to migrate the data present in an old DB to a new DB and I want to have a better schema to avoid redundant data
I know of the straight forward way of writing queries with INSERT and SELECT queries for each table, but there's a chance that I might miss some data. Is there a proven way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working on the basis that `DepartmentID` is a unique ID, you can use `SELECT DISTINCT` to obtain all unique Department IDs from the old table, e.g.

`SELECT DISTINCT DepartmentID FROM Old_Table;`

More information on the distinct keyword is provided in the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/distinct-optimization.html).

One issue you may encounter is that the same `DepartmentID` may have different Department Name and Department Address values in your database.  This is because you have a transitive dependency in your database; something we aim to avoid by adhering to Normal Forms.

Unfortunately solving this problem may require manually verifying and cleaning the data to ensure consistency in the Department Name and Department Address fields.

Comment: Thank you @bunnmatt